# Seeking the Optimal multi-threaded makefile for Fortran project with modules

Tags: makefile, module, fortran, gfortran

I have all my code inside modules and one module per sourcefile (besides minimal program after the module in the file tests.f90). The name of the source-files and modules are equal giving equivalent names, like: `src/computes.f90`, `build/computes.o`, `build/computes.mod`. There are `use` statements linking the modules to each other. The following is my best attempt at a good makefile for this project, but there is a major problem of files getting reconsidered *ad infinitum*.

**Idea:** One can compile only .mod-files quickly with `-fsyntax-only`. When all .mod-files exist, the .o-files have no internal dependencies and can be compiled in any order, easing multi-threaded compilation.

When a source is compiled, with our without `gfortran -fsyntax-only`, the module file is only updated in case it changes, regardless of whether the corresponding object file is updated. So one can have older `.mod` files than `.o` files corresponding to the same .f90-file.

If file.f90 is updated, the corresponding file.o should be updated and maybe file.mod. In case file.mod is updated, file2.mod, which depends on file.mod, should be checked with `gfortran -fsyntax-only file2.f90`. Only if file2.mod then gets updated, should file2.o also be compiled (which is the time-consuming step, and should be avoided otherwise. (Is this even correct?)).

**Implementation and problem:** I implemented these principles in the make-file below. But the problem appear in the (expected) case when file.mod is updated but not file2.mod. Then make will keep running `gfortran -fsyntax-only file2.f90` every time, because the prerequisite is older than the target which didn't (and shoudn't) update.

What can I do? Could I have the dependency file2.mod triggered only if file.mod is replaced (i.e. time when created), but have the file.mod itself only being considered by `make` judged on its latest `touch` (time of latest modification) for example? I also welcome suggestions for a different approach.

```
B = build
S = src
F = gfortran
f = -J$B -I$B 
P = program 

modfile_names = constypes computes systems tests

obj = $(addprefix $B/, $(modfile_names:=.o))   

vpath %.f90 $S

all:
    make -j4 $P

$P:$(obj)
    $F $f $^ -o $@

$B/%.o:%.f90 $B/%.mod
    $F $f -c $< -o $@

$B/%.mod:
    $F $f -fsyntax-only $S/$(notdir ${@:.mod=.f90}) 

$B/tests.mod: $B/constypes.mod $B/computes.mod $B/systems.mod
$B/computes.mod $B/systems.mod: $B/constypes.mod

.phony:clear
clear: 
    rm $B/* $P
```

Comment: Is the module recompilation cascade really that much of an issue?  I have projects with hundreds of modules, and it doesn't particularly bother me.  Personally I would consider splitting implementation into submodules before trying to force a build system in this way - consider what happens if you ever change compiler.

Comment: I don't understand how you have a module compilation cascade without using `-fsyntax-only`? It's not a big issue per se, but I want to find a clean solution to apply to a larger project. I have no experience with submodules, and that also implies more change of the sourcecode, but that is possible.

Comment: @IanH And regarding possible change of compiler you have a good point.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same structure for my code. Also, only if a source file is modified the `.o` file is updated but the `.mod` file can be older.
This is the makefile:

```
# Compiler options
FC  := $(F90) -cpp
FFLAGS  := -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-integer-8 -Wall -Wtabs -Ofast -fcheck=all -ffree-line-length-none -pthread

# Define directories
OOP_DIR :=  ../oop
MOD_DIR :=  ../build
vortZ2D_DIR := ..

# Define file extensions
.SUFFIXES: .f90 .o .mod

# Targets (objects)
OBJ  = $(MOD_DIR)/fft.o $(MOD_DIR)/grid.o $(MOD_DIR)/geom.o $(MOD_DIR)/body.o $(MOD_DIR)/fluid.o
OBJ1 = $(MOD_DIR)/vortZ2D.o
TAR1 = vortZ2D

# Build rules
all: runner | $(MOD_DIR)

$(MOD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(MOD_DIR)

$(MOD_DIR)/%.o: $(OOP_DIR)/%.f90 | $(MOD_DIR)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -J$(MOD_DIR)
$(MOD_DIR)/%.o: $(vortZ2D_DIR)/%.f90 | $(MOD_DIR)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(TAR1) ../vortZ2D.f90 -J$(MOD_DIR)

runner: $(OBJ) $(OBJ1)

clean:
    @if [ -d $(MOD_DIR) ]; then \
        rm -rf $(MOD_DIR) && echo "build/ cleaned"; \
    else \
        echo "nothing to clean"; \
    fi
run:
    @"make; ./vortZ2D; cd ../bin"
```

I have this makefile in a `/bin` folder. When a source file is updated in `/oop` there is no cascade triggered. You can include the `-fsyntax-only` flag to speed up if you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have a problem though in this file. You have no dependencies at all among the .o or .mod files (where the modules are), so if you change a sourcefile by adding a variable to a subroutine or changing the dimension of an arrays passed between modules, you migh have unexpected things happening, or an error in the linker step, I'm not sure. If you have no modules, then everything is fine probably but not applicable to my problem. But I did not know about the pipe command in makfiles, thanks for that!

Comment: Well, the modules are dependent from one to another actually. But I agree that if, for example, any variable is changed in a module there will be errors in the linker step. But this is actually alright as is just the way to realise where is the error propagating.